# How do i shorten my url like facebook do to users profile page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to shorten my website url of a newly added page event like

`mysite.com/asoebi/myevent` instead of `mysite.com/asoebi/index.php?event=myevent`

but every time i try to change my .htaccess file it give an error

[image]

here is .htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index/(\w+)$ ./index.php?event=$1

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this a WordPress web site?

Comment: Your new rule is never executed since the previous block (seems like a Wordpress rule) matches every non-existing files/folders. So you need to put your rule **before** it

Comment: @LeonardChallis no its not

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable mod_rewrite in apache for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this one in the `.htaccess` file in the `/public_html/asoebi/` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /asoebi/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?event=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

***Also remove the last rewriterule from the main htaccess file you posted above***

Comment: it is now showing the same page as it is on [http://faari.ng](http://faari.ng) page. i want to show page [http://faari.ng/asoebi/index.php?event=myevent](http://faari.ng/asoebi/index.php?event=myevent) when someone enters [http://faari.ng/asoebi/myevent](http://faari.ng/asoebi/myevent)

Comment: pls tell the directory where the htaccess file exists

Comment: it is placed in /public_html directory which is the main website and also in /public_html/asoebi directory which is the sub website on which i want to rewrite url

Comment: i did same as you told but after putting the htaccess file in /public_html/asoebi/ folder the website is not working properly even css is not loading

Comment: and Also remove the last rewriterule from the main htaccess file but whenever i write faari.ng/asoebi/myevent it shows the faari.ng page